# java hashmap with List as value to property

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have a HashMap in the following format.

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> map
```

I'm trying without any luck to find the best way to write this out to a property file, is this possible? I had no problem with a `HashMap<String, String> hashmap`, but when the value is a List I can't figure out the best way to store this out. I Don't care if it's out in xml format or any other format, just so I can easily open the file and have it serialized or whatever back into a hashmap.

Thanks for any direction

Comment: Properties are strings. Concat the `List` to comma separated. e.g. `value1,value2,value3,value4` and add it to your Properties object.

Comment: @BrianRoach that would assume that the values Strings do not contain commas.

Comment: @John - Well, yes. And if they did you could quote the values, use pipe instead of comma, etc ... not rocket science :)

Comment: @BrianRoach Don't say that! I might not paid as much! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A HashMap is Serializable; so you can do this by default.

```
FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream("map.map");
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
os.writeObject(map);
os.close();
```

Comment: This is what I was hoping to do, my value that is a List is a subList and that is causing a problem, but not sure the best way around it yet.

Answer (score 4):

First, you might want to consider using a [`ListMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/index.html) from Guava. It implements a `Map<Key, List<Value>>`.

Next, I would set up an XML Schema where each element has a name and a list of values. Use JAXB to marshall the data to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are currently doing, but you can always just get a set of the `Map.Entry<String,List<String>>` instances that compose the map and write them out any way you want.  See [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29).

The psuedo code would look something like

```
for (Map.Entry<String,List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    List<String> value = entry.getValue();

    // now loop over value, which will be of type List<String>
}
```